# How do I get Pfsense to automatically assign fqdn for each host in my local network

Tags: networking, dns, active-directory, pfsense

Is there a solution on PfSense that would assign a fully qualified domain name to a host automatically?

I want the new computers that join my network to get assigned a new FQDN automatically, instead of manually changing the DNS configuration every time. I'm planning on implementing VMware with several virtual machines, and having to do the task manually would become a tedious task over time.

Is Active Directory from Microsoft the only solution out there that would accomplish this task?

Comment: Tim, I believe you are right! The FQDN is assigned to a host by the DHCP server on the Windows domain structure once that host has joined the domain. I’m using the latest version of Pfsense.